# Django /gunicorn: ImportError: cannot import name get_path_info

Tags: django, gunicorn

I installed requirements for a project I am trying to run and they installed fine.Then I ran foreman start and I got this error and I can't understand what the issue is here. Any Ideas? I tried uninstalling and reinstalling dj_static, did't seem to make a difference.

```
(venv)$ foreman start
    16:28:12 web.1  | started with pid 29309
    16:28:12 web.1  | 2014-05-12 16:28:12 [29309] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
    16:28:12 web.1  | 2014-05-12 16:28:12 [29309] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (29309)
    16:28:12 web.1  | 2014-05-12 16:28:12 [29309] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    16:28:12 web.1  | 2014-05-12 16:28:12 [29312] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29312
    16:28:12 web.1  | 2014-05-12 16:28:12 [29312] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
    16:28:12 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
    16:28:12 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    16:28:12 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
    16:28:12 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    16:28:12 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
    16:28:12 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    16:28:12 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
    16:28:12 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    16:28:12 web.1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
    16:28:12 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    16:28:12 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
    16:28:12 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    16:28:12 web.1  |     __import__(module)
    16:28:12 web.1  |   File "/Users/n/wppdashboard/dashboard/wsgi.py", line 25, in <module>
    16:28:12 web.1  |     from dj_static import Cling
    16:28:12 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dj_static.py", line 7, in <module>
    16:28:12 web.1  |     from django.core.handlers.base import get_path_info
    16:28:12 web.1  | ImportError: cannot import name get_path_info
    16:28:12 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
    16:28:12 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    16:28:12 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
    16:28:12 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    16:28:12 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
    16:28:12 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    16:28:12 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
    16:28:12 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    16:28:12 web.1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
    16:28:12 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    16:28:12 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
    16:28:12 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    16:28:12 web.1  |     __import__(module)
    16:28:12 web.1  |   File "/Users/n/wppdashboard/dashboard/wsgi.py", line 25, in <module>
    16:28:12 web.1  |     from dj_static import Cling
    16:28:12 web.1  |   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dj_static.py", line 7, in <module>
    16:28:12 web.1  |     from django.core.handlers.base import get_path_info
    16:28:12 web.1  | ImportError: cannot import name get_path_info
    16:28:12 web.1  | 2014-05-12 16:28:12 [29312] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 29312)
    16:28:12 web.1  | 2014-05-12 16:28:12 [29309] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
    16:28:12 web.1  | 2014-05-12 16:28:12 [29309] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
    16:28:12 web.1  | exited with code 3
    16:28:12 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
    SIGTERM received
    (venv)$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this one out.

I either had installed two different versions or I had changed some file in the installation. Just reinstall django in your venv and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the problem was that `dj_static` `0.0.5` didn't seem to be playing nicely with Django 1.7. I upgraded to `0.0.6` and it fixed it.

Comment: thanks man! that's what worked for me after the upgrade to Django 1.7.

Comment: Worked after upgrade from Django 1.6 to 1.8. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am running on OpenShift, and received the same error while upgrading from Django 1.6 to 1.7.  In my openshiftstaticfiles.py, I made the following change in the "imports" section at the top of the module.

```
try:
    #Django 1.7
    from django.core.handlers.wsgi import get_path_info
except ImportError:
    #Django 1.6
    from django.core.handlers.base import get_path_info
```

I dont think I am using 'dj_static', but it is using 'static3', which I see in my root level 'setup.py' file.